# Dynamic drop down menu style selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Fonts extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            value: "",
            current: "",
        };
        this.fontHandler = this.fontHandler.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    fontHandler(event){
        this.setState({
            fontFamily: event.target.current,
            current: this.state.onChange
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ current: this.state.onSubmit });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h1 style={{fontFamily: this.state.current }}>Yuh Yeet</h1>
                    <select onChange = {this.state.value}>
                        <option value="Anton">Anton</option>
                        <option value="Calistoga">Calistoga</option>
                        <option value="Fira Sans">Fira Sans</option>
                        <option value="Noto Serif">Noto Serif</option>
                        <option value="Quicksand">Quicksand</option>
                        <option value="Ubuntu">Ubuntu</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                        <option value="Titillium Web">Titillium Web</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit"> Change </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the inline style of the h1 tag by selecting the desired font from a dropdown menu I provide. My problem is that my selected font isn't being brought in to change my style. I'm importing all my fonts into my index.html from Google Fonts, so that isn't the problem. Am I just calling the state wrong or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works. A couple notes:

- Taki is right, you don't need the onSubmit handler. However if you don't use one the font will change as soon as it's selected, not when the "change" button is clicked. As a second note in Taki's solution, the fontHandler function would not give you the desired result in terms of setting the state. If that function was used, the state would have to be set to `current: value.target.value`
- When using the `setState()`, two notes. 1 - You don't want to refer to what the current state is. You want to use prevState. State updates are sometimes batched together which means there will be times where you have an error. 2 - You don't want to reference the eventHandler for two reasons. The first is that it won't know what you're referencing. `onChange` and `onSubmit` are not functions that are defined in your component, they are attributes to `<form>` and `select` respectively. Second is that you really shouldn't try to reference functions in state. Create the function outside of the state object and call it to set the state that you want to change
- I set the initial state to the first select option. Won't affect the functionality of your app but it will make the user experience better if the default font isn't set to Anton.

As a side note, look into using Hooks and Arrow functions. They'll make your life easier and your code cleaner.

Hope this helps you understand why your code isn't working. Yeet yeet.

```
export default class Fonts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFont: "Anton",
      displayedFont: "Anton"
    };
    this.fontHandler = this.fontHandler.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  fontHandler(event) {
    const font = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      selectedFont: font
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      displayedFont: prevState.selectedFont
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state)}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h1 style={{ fontFamily: this.state.displayedFont }}>Yuh Yeet</h1>
          <select onChange={this.fontHandler}>
            <option value="Anton">Anton</option>
            <option value="Calistoga">Calistoga</option>
            <option value="Fira Sans">Fira Sans</option>
            <option value="Noto Serif">Noto Serif</option>
            <option value="Quicksand">Quicksand</option>
            <option value="Ubuntu">Ubuntu</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Titillium Web">Titillium Web</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit"> Change </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I had been working on this for a a while and I thought I was just making it worse as I tried to fix it XD. This resulted in the various variables and functions kind of everywhere. I has used prevState in another font-sizer page I had made but hadn't thought about font being changed that way. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with your code, the `select`'s `onChange` needs to point to `fontHandler` which updates the state to set the `current` value :

```
<select onChange={this.fontHandler}>
  // ...
</select>
```

fontHandler :

```
fontHandler(value){
  this.setState({      
      current: value
  });
}
```

no need to submit.

Comment: Thanks!. My initial attempt was supposed to be an onChange, but I decided to make this apart of a larger text editor page. I appreciate the help!